# MacOS Bash in IntelliJ: stop copying things on selection

Tags: macos, shell, intellij-idea, terminal, iterm2

The bash shell in IntelliJ in MacOS is currently very misconfigured for me and this appears to be a default configuration. When I click into it and select a text it is automatically copied. That means every time I switch between windows and click into the shell in IntelliJ, I have to very cautious that the click really is just a click and I don't drag the mouse by accident because then everything from my clipboard is lost and I have copied some random letters. My current workaround is to not use the intellij terminal at all but to open iTerm from the iterm-button-plugin. But surely there must be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just untick this checkbox

[image]